# Alternative ways for plotting p-values: hide.ns function is not working with updated ggpubr

Tags: ggpubr

This is my data frame:
‘‘‘

```
structure(Data2)
       Analysis_region Phenotypes     Value Tissue Subsets          ROI
1        GC_outer4    CD20pd1  4.621072  lymph       B Cortex_outer
2       GC3_outer1    CD20pd1  7.397959  lymph       B Cortex_outer
3        GC_outer3    CD20pd1 20.445344  lymph       B Cortex_outer
4      GC_subcaps2    CD20pd1 28.001505  lymph       B  Subcapsular
5        GC_inner2    CD20pd1  9.602401  lymph       B Cortex_inner
6        GC_inner3    CD20pd1 10.165074  lymph       B Cortex_inner
7        GC_outer2    CD20pd1  7.661521  lymph       B Cortex_outer
8        GC_inner1    CD20pd1  9.861213  lymph       B Cortex_inner
9      GC_subcaps3    CD20pd1 16.797797  lymph       B  Subcapsular
10     GC_subcaps4    CD20pd1  6.007394  lymph       B  Subcapsular
11     GC_subcaps1    CD20pd1 13.490364  lymph       B  Subcapsular
12     GC_subcaps5    CD20pd1 19.073569  lymph       B  Subcapsular
13     GC_subcaps6    CD20pd1  4.571429  lymph       B  Subcapsular
14       GC_outer5    CD20pd1  5.226960  lymph       B Cortex_outer
15     GC_subcaps7    CD20pd1  2.901915  lymph       B  Subcapsular
16       GC_outer6    CD20pd1  8.238145  lymph       B Cortex_outer
17       GC_outer7    CD20pd1  5.537721  lymph       B Cortex_outer
18       GC_inner4    CD20pd1  1.005484  lymph       B Cortex_inner
19       GC_inner5    CD20pd1  1.365854  lymph       B Cortex_inner
20       GC_inner6    CD20pd1  3.838384  lymph       B Cortex_inner
21       GC_inner7    CD20pd1  3.783231  lymph       B Cortex_inner
22       GC_outer4     CD4pd1 12.593985  lymph      T4 Cortex_outer
23      GC3_outer1     CD4pd1 11.028037  lymph      T4 Cortex_outer
24       GC_outer3     CD4pd1 27.798098  lymph      T4 Cortex_outer
25     GC_subcaps2     CD4pd1 45.018116  lymph      T4  Subcapsular
26       GC_inner2     CD4pd1 27.980535  lymph      T4 Cortex_inner
27       GC_inner3     CD4pd1 23.372781  lymph      T4 Cortex_inner
28       GC_outer2     CD4pd1 15.112540  lymph      T4 Cortex_outer
29       GC_inner1     CD4pd1 19.222904  lymph      T4 Cortex_inner
30     GC_subcaps3     CD4pd1 35.986159  lymph      T4  Subcapsular
31     GC_subcaps4     CD4pd1 19.098143  lymph      T4  Subcapsular
32     GC_subcaps1     CD4pd1 31.833910  lymph      T4  Subcapsular
33     GC_subcaps5     CD4pd1 18.995929  lymph      T4  Subcapsular
34     GC_subcaps6     CD4pd1  4.540163  lymph      T4  Subcapsular
35       GC_outer5     CD4pd1  7.210626  lymph      T4 Cortex_outer
36     GC_subcaps7     CD4pd1 11.282051  lymph      T4  Subcapsular
37       GC_outer6     CD4pd1 17.187500  lymph      T4 Cortex_outer
38       GC_outer7     CD4pd1 17.123288  lymph      T4 Cortex_outer
39       GC_inner4     CD4pd1  2.334630  lymph      T4 Cortex_inner
40       GC_inner5     CD4pd1  1.805869  lymph      T4 Cortex_inner
41       GC_inner6     CD4pd1 13.953488  lymph      T4 Cortex_inner
42       GC_inner7     CD4pd1  6.514658  lymph      T4 Cortex_inner
43       GC_outer4     CD8pd1  0.000000  lymph      T8 Cortex_outer
44      GC3_outer1     CD8pd1  0.000000  lymph      T8 Cortex_outer
45       GC_outer3     CD8pd1 20.512821  lymph      T8 Cortex_outer
46     GC_subcaps2     CD8pd1 26.470588  lymph      T8  Subcapsular
47       GC_inner2     CD8pd1  8.450704  lymph      T8 Cortex_inner
48       GC_inner3     CD8pd1  8.474576  lymph      T8 Cortex_inner
49       GC_outer2     CD8pd1  0.000000  lymph      T8 Cortex_outer
50       GC_inner1     CD8pd1  0.000000  lymph      T8 Cortex_inner
51     GC_subcaps3     CD8pd1 12.244898  lymph      T8  Subcapsular
52     GC_subcaps4     CD8pd1  0.000000  lymph      T8  Subcapsular
53     GC_subcaps1     CD8pd1  0.000000  lymph      T8  Subcapsular
54     GC_subcaps5     CD8pd1 11.111111  lymph      T8  Subcapsular
55     GC_subcaps6     CD8pd1  0.000000  lymph      T8  Subcapsular
56       GC_outer5     CD8pd1  0.000000  lymph      T8 Cortex_outer
57     GC_subcaps7     CD8pd1  0.000000  lymph      T8  Subcapsular
58       GC_outer6     CD8pd1  2.608696  lymph      T8 Cortex_outer
59       GC_outer7     CD8pd1  0.000000  lymph      T8 Cortex_outer
60       GC_inner4     CD8pd1  0.000000  lymph      T8 Cortex_inner
61       GC_inner5     CD8pd1  0.000000  lymph      T8 Cortex_inner
62       GC_inner6     CD8pd1  0.000000  lymph      T8 Cortex_inner
63       GC_inner7     CD8pd1  0.000000  lymph      T8 Cortex_inner
64       GC_outer4    CD68pd1  0.000000  lymph     M68 Cortex_outer
65      GC3_outer1    CD68pd1  0.000000  lymph     M68 Cortex_outer
66       GC_outer3    CD68pd1  0.000000  lymph     M68 Cortex_outer
67     GC_subcaps2    CD68pd1 50.000000  lymph     M68  Subcapsular
68       GC_inner2    CD68pd1  0.000000  lymph     M68 Cortex_inner
69       GC_inner3    CD68pd1  0.000000  lymph     M68 Cortex_inner
70       GC_outer2    CD68pd1  0.000000  lymph     M68 Cortex_outer
71       GC_inner1    CD68pd1  0.000000  lymph     M68 Cortex_inner
72     GC_subcaps3    CD68pd1  0.000000  lymph     M68  Subcapsular
73     GC_subcaps4    CD68pd1  0.000000  lymph     M68  Subcapsular
74     GC_subcaps1    CD68pd1  0.000000  lymph     M68  Subcapsular
75     GC_subcaps5    CD68pd1  0.000000  lymph     M68  Subcapsular
76     GC_subcaps6    CD68pd1  0.000000  lymph     M68  Subcapsular
77       GC_outer5    CD68pd1  0.000000  lymph     M68 Cortex_outer
78     GC_subcaps7    CD68pd1  0.000000  lymph     M68  Subcapsular
79       GC_outer6    CD68pd1  0.000000  lymph     M68 Cortex_outer
80       GC_outer7    CD68pd1  0.000000  lymph     M68 Cortex_outer
81       GC_inner4    CD68pd1  0.000000  lymph     M68 Cortex_inner
82       GC_inner5    CD68pd1  0.000000  lymph     M68 Cortex_inner
83       GC_inner6    CD68pd1  0.000000  lymph     M68 Cortex_inner
84       GC_inner7    CD68pd1  0.000000  lymph     M68 Cortex_inner
```

‘‘‘

These are the codes for boxplots and facet:

```
‘‘‘

library(tidyverse)
       library(dplyr)
       library(ggplot2)
       library(ggpubr)
       library(rstatix)
        Reorder the levels of the "ROI" variable
          Data2$ROI <- factor(Data2$ROI, levels = c("Cortex_inner", "Cortex_outer",
          "Subcapsular"))

       p1 = ggboxplot(Data2, x = "ROI", y = "Value", color = "ROI",
               add ="jitter") +
       theme_classic()+ylim(0,100)+
       facet_grid(cols=vars(Subsets), rows=vars(Tissue))+
       labs(x=" ", y = "% PD1 positive", fill = "Region of Interest") +
       labs(color = "ROI")+
       ggtitle("Lymph_panc PD1") +
       rotate_x_text(angle= 45) +
       theme(legend.position = "none",
        strip.text = element_text(size = 9))
         p1

      ##Statistics

     kruskal_result <- kruskal.test(Value ~ ROI, data = Data2)


      my_comparison= list(c("Cortex_inner","Cortex_outer"),
       c("Cortex_inner","Subcapsular"), 
       c("Cortex_outer", "Subcapsular"))

        p2 = p1 + stat_compare_means(aes(group = ROI), 
        method = "wilcox.test", label =     "p.format", hide.ns = TRUE, 
                             comparisons = my_comparison, tip.length = 0)
         p2‘‘‘
```

I would appreciate if anyone could help with the plotting of p values. The function hide.ns does not work with my codes. I have multiple comparisons across groups, and they are all ns. The ggpubr function hide.ns is not working. I also attached the plot.